# GPU - what is the benefit of additional shader cores and VRAM?

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, nvidia-quadro, vram

I am about to get a new laptop.  I am going to use the laptop for video editing/encoding, on-the-fly screen recording of internet videos (so I don't want the video playback to be jerky while it's trying to record), and some gaming.  It will be running 1080p resolution, and there's a chance at some point in the future I'll put it in a docking station with 3 monitors attached.  I also hope to be able to use the laptop for at least 5 years, so I want to future proof it reasonably well.

For the GPU, I can choose between the Nvidia Quadro K3100M, K4100M, or K5100M.

The [K3100M](http://www.notebookcheck.net/NVIDIA-Quadro-K3100M.98854.0.html) has the following specs:

- Shader Cores: 768
- Core Speed: 706 MHz
- Memory Speed: 3200 MHz
- Video RAM: 4 GB

The [K4100M](http://www.notebookcheck.net/NVIDIA-Quadro-K4100M.98852.0.html) has the following specs:

- Shader Cores: 1152
- Core Speed: 706 MHz
- Memory Speed: 3200 MHz
- Video RAM: 4 GB

The [K5100M](http://www.notebookcheck.net/NVIDIA-Quadro-K5100M.98851.0.html) has the following specs:

- Shader Cores: 1536
- Core Speed: 771 MHz
- Memory Speed: 3600 MHz
- Video RAM: 8 GB

What kind of applications require the maximum number of shader cores and 8GB of video RAM?  I am wondering if I would benefit from the K5100M's ~400 additional shader cores and extra 4GB of video RAM, as well as its ~10% increase in core/memory speed.  If there would be no benefit to the K5100M, then would there be any benefit to the K4100M's ~400 additional shader cores over the K3100M?  The K4100M and K3100M seem to be exactly the same except for the number of shader cores.

Comment: This is just mainly for rendering and video games if you are planning on doing any of that, if not it would be a waste considering those specs.

Comment: I don't think the 4GB vs 8GB will be noticeable for your purposes but I can assure you that the higher clock speeds will be noticeable for both of your purposes. Heck, you can run 6 monitors on GPUs with 1GB vRAM but gaming across all 6 monitors is where you would absolutely need more vRAM.

Comment: You supplied your own info in the links. most of the 3D stuff, games, Cad , 3D render can be parellel processed , the quantity of these cores gets pretty relative to the speed of doing so.  The 8g is probably overkill for the total ammount of textures and data that would be in the v-ram the screen buffers do not take much total v-ram, but the gpu chip features could still determine the max reses for one or more monitors.

Comment: @Psycogeek Can you supply the missing word in your sentence "the quantity of these cores gets pretty ??? relative to the speed of doing so".  I'm not doing any CAD or 3D rendering (or does movie editing still involve 3D?).  I guess I might play some 3D games, but that's not a priority for me.

Comment: ok in simple the 768 vrses the 1536 could render up to 2X FPS game 3D graphics depending of course on many other things. The cores are a very important spec to look for when intending to run 3D games.

Comment: Movie editing would completly depend, every day they apply more and more of the GPU in the video programs, sometimes unnessisarily. simple cuts never really required the work a gpu is best at. All the effects stuff though can be rendered many times faster when that processing is done in parelell as 3d in the gpu. Progress for video programs has been to move most of that work to the gpu. If your going to be using a lot of effects, not simple cuts like movies are known for, or you have a lot of GCI effects, you will want to have a better GPU.

Comment: @Ramhound Not at all.  I will make my own decision on which GPU to get.  I just didn't know if additional shader cores and memory would benefit my usage scenarios.  In addition, the K5100M/K4100M/K3100M are all from the same generation (released in 2013).  The previous generation was K5000M/K4000M/K3000M (released in 2012).

Comment: Bloody Nvidia and their naming conventions...

Answer (score 2):

> what is the benefit of additional shader cores

The more shader cores, the faster the shading can be applied during rendering.

[More info on Shares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shader)

> and VRAM?

VRAM is much faster than shared system RAM when it comes to memory usage for the video. A video adapter having it's own VRAM relieve the system RAM of the video tasks, so that the RAM can be used to make other (ie: non-video) functions perform faster.

The more VRAM on the card, the less system RAM will be used for video functions.  Of lesser  importance in today's world of multi-GB video cards, the amount of available VRAM generally defines how high of a resolution (and colour depth) the card can support.

> What kind of applications require the maximum number of shader cores and 8GB of video RAM?

Graphically intensive ones that are generating/rendering images on the fly. Games, CAD, etc.

Comment: The shader Wiki page says "Shaders are most commonly used to produce lighting and shadow in 3D modeling."  If I am trying to screen record an internet video, would that even involve 3D?  Wondering if additional shaders would help with that.

Comment: In general, no, as recording video is not generating/rendering graphics.  I would image you _could_ use Shaders during video recording to apply image processing on the fly, if your video recording software supported that.

Comment: So then the speed of the GPU is really the only thing that matters for video recording.

Comment: Or could the CPU matter more than the GPU for video recording?

Comment: Screen capturing you desktop (unless it's at some ridiculously high resolution) should be easily handled by even low-end modern equipment.

Comment: I tried screen capturing on a laptop from 2012 (either 1366x768 or 1600x900 resolution) and the videos it saved were jerky and sometimes had the audio out of sync with the video.

Comment: Then something else was going on IMO.  Or it is just a REALLY crappy laptop.  I use to regularly capture 1280x1024 on my P4 from 2003, without incident. ;)  Anyhow, figuring out why you had jittery video with audio lag is out-side the scope of this question/answer.

Comment: I hope you don't mind one more follow-up on the shaders.  Would Blu-Ray and other HD video playback count as "generating/rendering images on the fly" and would benefit from more shaders?